# A matrix as a point in $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, intuition

I just had a really quick question to ask. I was reading a book on linear algebra and have just been trying to wrap my head around what exactly a matrix represents. At one point, the book said

"In a more formal sense an $m × n$ matrix $A$ can be thought of as a point in $\mathbb R^{nm}$, with the agreement that the entries are ordered into rows and columns rather than a single row or single column."

I didn't really understand what this meant. What is a point in $\mathbb R^{nm}$ from an intuitive/not so abstract perspective? Does it mean literally the vector space $\mathbb R^{n × m}$ e.g a $2 × 3$ matrix represents a point in $\mathbb R^{6}$ except instead of the 6-tuple written with 6 entries in one row or 6 entries in one column they are written in both rows and columns?

Comment: I think that last line is exactly what it represents.

Comment: this is just an abstract way of saying that in a matrix, there are $m \times n$ coefficients. To understand matrices, thinking of them as a $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$ vector is certainly not the good way ! Just keep the array representation.

Comment: yes. That's what it means. So if we were doing it by rows we could identify the point $p=(1,1,2,2)\in \mathbb{R}^4$ by the matrix $$p=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$. So $n\times m$ matrices are a subset of $F^{m\times n}$ space. Or you can think of them as linear transformations $F^m\rightarrow F^n$ (or $F^n\rightarrow F^m$ if you multiply on the other side).

Comment: are you familiar with term isomorphism? Then you can think of the vector space of matrices and the corresponding euclidean vectorspace and they are isomorphic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using your example, a matrix:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is an element of a vector space that , in the standard basis, is represented as:
$$
A=
a_{11}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0\\
0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}+
a_{12}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
0&0\\
0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}+
a_{21}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\
1&0\\
0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}+
a_{22}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\
0&1\\
0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}+
a_{31}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\
0&0\\
1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}+
a_{32}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\
0&0\\
0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

so it can be represented by a vector $[a_{11},a_{12},a_{21},a_{22},a_{31},a_{32}]$ in this space that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 3}$

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!